# Google Marketplace App Install Flow

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

When installing a Google Marketplace App, the flow usually ends with the admin in the app's settings on Google with the option to sign in now. Is there a way to end with the user actually using the app (i.e. not having to click the link to sign in to start using the app)? Could the user just be sent to the app on the optional setup without returning to the app settings page on Google without that causing other problems?

Some of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/lifecycle) says:

> We strongly recommend that the administrator be directed through a short, linear series of actions and returned to Google quickly so additional users can start using the application.

<s>I tried testing this out, but it seems like there's some lag between installing and the app showing up in the "more" drop down for Google (I tried installing another app and did end up on the final page but the app still didn't show up in another account. It's been a few hours and it still isn't there) so it's hard to tell if it's just slow or not actually installed on other users' accounts.</s>

Sorry the last section was misleading. This is not a question about the link not showing up immediately.

Comment: Please note we have released a new experience for the Google Apps Marketplace ([see announcement](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2013/11/third-party-apps-now-easier-to-find-and.html)). We also have new [Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/).

The install flow is slightly different but the link should appear a lot sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new experience for Google Apps Marketplace lets you land the user in the app instead of the admin console. There's now a popup for the app to request permissions and to agree to terms and then the user ends up in the app. One-step installation. Good work Google.