# Setup Url for Google Apps Marketplace (GAMv2) doesn't redirect

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I've created a test listing for Google Apps Marketplace (GAMv2) and have specified a setup url.  When testing using the "TEST INSTALL FLOW" button, the authorization screen pops up and clicking the "Accept" button takes me to a popup that confirms the application has been added.  There's a "Launch app" button and a "Manage app" link on this 2nd popup.  The "Launch app" button goes to the setup url that I entered in the listing definition.

Isn't the install flow supposed to redirect there automatically?  I've seen other questions where this behaviour seems to be working on and off:

- [Google Marketplace App Install Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247563/google-marketplace-app-install-flow)
- [Google Apps Marketplace SDK install does not forward user to Setup URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559130/google-apps-marketplace-sdk-install-does-not-forward-user-to-setup-url)
- [Google app marketplace sdk setup url stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225585/google-app-marketplace-sdk-setup-url-stopped-working)

There's also this page in the marketplace documentation which says it is supposed to redirect:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/eap/oauthwalkthrough

Are other people having this problem?

Comment: same here, when user integrates with our application and clicks "done" in the integration popup, nothing happens and user stays in the installed application page without any explicit instructions. this is a bad user experience, the reasonable flow should be something like clicking "done" and opening the setup url.

Comment: I had to make a workaround in my application, making the user to log in with his google account and check if app installed for his domain. if installed, trigger setup url and move along the regular installation flow.

Answer (score 1):

In v1 of the marketplace, yes, set up links were automatically included in the linear install flow. In the new install flow set up links are presented separately. They're presented to users, but there is no guarantee that that a user will click it. Even in V1 there were some cases where a user could end up bypassing the setup link.

There are some improvements that can be made to encourage admins to revisit the setup if they skipped it. In either case, apps should be tolerant of these cases and adapt.

My recommendation is to check on login and enter the setup flow if it hasn't yet been performed. You can use the licensing API to check if the domain has installed from the marketplace or not. If you need to enforce things like requiring admin permissions, you can add further checks to see if the current user is an admin for the domain and give non-admin users a polite message indicating the app isn't ready for them to use yet.