# After installing an app on the Marketplace, how to allow the admin to visit settings page?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am working on an app that will be listed on Google Marketplace. In the introductory video on [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/) I saw a Settings link after the install. How do I specify such a link? Should it be put in the `manifest.json` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a `Setup URL` that can be configured in the Marketplace API page. But it might not be visited by the administrator so we should use the licensing API to check whether the app was installed as suggested in the accepted answer [Setup Url for Google Apps Marketplace (GAMv2) doesn't redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020214/setup-url-for-google-apps-marketplace-gamv2-doesnt-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

You can allow to visit the settings page by [granting or revoking data access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176367). You can see a summary of the data an app has access to by clicking Data access. If the app has access to your domain’s data, it will say Granted. If the app does not have access to your domain’s data, it will say Approval Needed. If the app requires API access to your Google Apps data, those APIs are listed in this section.

Note: If the app is enabled and requires [data access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172981), and you revoke data access, the app may not function properly.

You can review the data access requirements for an app during installation, or afterwards on the app's Settings page.

Apps may also access identity-related information about your users through standard programmatic access. In no case should third-party apps have access to any of your domain passwords.